# Finding the status of scanner through PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, hardware

In our application we need to scan some documents and it should save to disk directly. 
Now we need to make one button to scan. That button should find the status of scanner.
If the status of scanner is connected it’s should proceed and it’s not connected it should display some errors like Scanner not connected when I click the button.

Comment: I can answer you the question but only if you buy the scanner I sell to you and then tell you which operating system you have to use... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of **[phpSANE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsane/)**. It's available on SourceForge and it does all what you have mentioned in the context so you don't have to code it again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I downloaded phpSane, but when I tried running it on browser i got an error saying-"The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." ERROR-500. Please let me know the solution for this.

Comment: Delete the `.htaccess` file inside the folder and you should be fine.

Comment: ya Shankar its working fine. but still am getting error like  No scanners were identified.
If you were expecting something different, check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate).